# How to estimate parameters from BG / NBD model using bbmle?

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate the probability for a customer to be alive after a certain period. I have data for 500 customers of a firm. For each customer I know x (number of transactions by a given customer over all time periods), tx (time of the last transaction) and T (total time between the first purchase and the end of the observation window).

I work with the BG/NBD model. In order to estimate the probability to be alive, I first need to estimate 4 parameters (r, alpha, a and b) included in this model. To optimize the value of these parameters, I am using the « bbmle » package (shown below).

However when I run the code, it doesn’t give any result. Furthermore it also seems that R doesn’t recognise many of the « objects » that are included in the functions below.

Does anyone notice any error that I’ve made in the code ? Is there another way to write it ?

```
bgLlh <- function(mydata, r, alpha, a, b) {
  with (mydata, {
    if (a<=0 | b<=0 | r<=0 | alpha<=0) return (NaN)
    term1 <-log(gamma(r+mydata$x)) - log(gamma(r)) + r*log(alpha)
    term2 <-log(gamma(a+b))+log(gamma(b+mydata$x))-log(gamma(b))-log(gamma(a+b+mydata$x))
    term3<- -(r+mydata$x)*log(alpha+mydata$T)
    term4 <- if(mydata$x > 1) {log(a)-log(b+mydata$x-1)-(r+mydata$x)*log(alpha+mydata$tx)
                              } else {0}

    llh <- term1 + term2 +log(exp(term3)+(mydata$x>0)*exp(term4))
    f <- -sum(llh)
    return(f)
  })
}

bgEstimateParameters <- function(mydata, initValues, safeMode=FALSE) {
  llhd <- function(r, alpha, a, b) {    
    return (bgLlh(data, r, alpha, a, b))
  }
  library(bbmle)
  if (safeMode) {
    fit <- mle2(llhd, initValues, skip.hessian=TRUE, method="Nelder-Mead")
  } else {
    fit <- mle2(llhd, initValues)
  }
  return (fit)
}
```

Comment: You need to include str(.) output on those input objects AND the code you are using to call the functions.

Comment: shouldn't you have `bgLlh(mydata...` in `bgEstimateParameters`?

Comment: a reproducible example http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 would sure be nice ...